# Alter Table Drop Column Failed

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to clean up a database table and I'd really like to drop two columns as they should no longer be being used.

```
'Property' table
- Unable to modify table.  
The index '_dta_index_Property_7_669245439__K1_K9_K8_K24_K4_2_5_6_13_22_25_26_29' is dependent on column 'AveragePriceMta'.
The index '_dta_index_Property_7_669245439__K1_K9_K8_K24_2_4_5_6_7_13_22_25_26_29' is dependent on column 'AveragePriceMta'.
ALTER TABLE DROP COLUMN AveragePriceMta failed because one or more objects access this column.
```

I've gone and looked at the indexes for this table found the particular columns I want to delete in a greyed out field of "Included columns".  Obviously I don't want to just drop these indexes - but is there a way to refresh the index so that I can remove the columns in question out of the non-editable included columns field?

Using SQL Server 2008 but database is 2005.. in case that matters.

Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: What happened to your caps lock key when you are typing your question title?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't add or remove columns to an Index.  You will have to drop the index and the re-create it.

You can you use `Create Index` along with the `Drop_Existing` clause to do this.

[MS Help on Create Index](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188783.aspx)